# Вылетает visual studio 2019 при открытии панель элементов

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-studio

Создаю проект c# или c++ windows forms(.net fremework) вроде все нормально но при открытие "Панели элементов" visual studio вылетает что делать.

У меня win 7 64 bit 4 GB

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Посмотреть в журнале windows, что за ошибка

Comment: aepot вот скрин точнее https://photos.app.goo.gl/vi3VxoWjueJjve4z5

Comment: Обновите систему, установите все пакеты обновлений. А еще лучше - замените на десятку.